# Unity OnDestroy Singleton

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public class SingletonMonoBehaviour<T> : MonoBehaviour where T: SingletonMonoBehaviour<T>
{
    private static T _instance;
    public static T instance { 
        get { 
            if (_instance == null) {
                var go = new GameObject(typeof(T).Name);
                _instance = go.AddComponent<T>();
                DontDestroyOnLoad(_instance);
            }
            return _instance;
        } 
    }
    
    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = (T)this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        Debug.Log("OnDisable " + this.name);
    }

    private void OnDestroy() {
        Debug.Log("OnDestroy " + this.name);
    }
}
```

I have a singleton class like this.
There is also a `Counter` that this singleton implements and an `Observable` class that monitors the change in `Counter`.

I can create this `Counter` on the scene, it will get into `DontDestroyOnLoad` via Awake. And I can not create it and it will be created through the first request to it and will also get into `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

It seems to be the same thing that I will create a Counter with my hands, that it will be created by self, as a result it will be in `DontDestroyOnLoad`.
But something is wrong here. I added logs to `OnDisable` and `onDestroy` for these two classes.

And on completion I get the following sequence.
The first time I create a Counter on the stage with my hands:

- OnDisable Observable
- OnDestroy Observable
- OnDisable Counter
- OnDestroy Counter

Everything is fine here (well, relatively, since I thought that first all `OnDisable` should be worked out, and then go to `onDestroy`, but it turned out that each object has its own sequence). First, unsubscribe from the event, and then delete the source of the event itself.

But in the case when I do not create an object on the scene and it is created by itself when requested, I see the following:

- OnDisable Counter
- OnDestroy Counter
- OnDisable Observable
- OnDestroy Observable

And the error:

`Some objects were not cleaned up when closing the scene. (Did you spawn new GameObjects from OnDestroy?) The following scene GameObjects were found: Counter`.

And here it is clear why the error. Since we have already deleted the `Counter`, and in `Observable` we refer to its instance, and since it is null, it creates it anew.

I thought it was an accident, but no, it's a pattern, and this happens every time you start.

And I have a question why is the sequence changing so much and is it possible to control it somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Singletons in unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591803/how-to-use-singletons-in-unity)

Comment: To make singletons in Unity you should avoid using `static` and instead "hang" them off well-known _singleton GameObjects_ in the scene.  See the link above.

Comment: @MickyD My question is not about static. This is a standard singleton that everyone uses.  I don't think it's a good idea to search by tag. If I did as you do, I would search by type, not by tag, so it would be safer. But that's not the question. In one case, the object has static access, I just create it myself on the stage, and in the other, only there it is created by itself. And my question is, why do they have a different deletion sequence? The objects seem to be the same, in both cases it is an empty object with one `Counter` component (with static in both cases).

Comment: _"This is a standard singleton that everyone uses"_ - incorrect.  Just because you can use C# doesn't mean all the well-known patterns apply.  Remember Unity is a native application that is also a CLR Host.  It controls .NET object lifetimes and doesn't like it when you have what are essentially orphaned .NET objects. Unity can and **will** destroy .NET objects **including** `static`s when it tears-down and re-creates the App Domain.   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html.   You also never use `static`s in custom editors.

Comment: _"I don't think it's a good idea to search by tag"_ -  there are many ways to search for objects, tag is just one and then test for a particular type.  If I fail to find it I fall-back to search-by-type however the former is considerably faster than the latter so it's a good idea to follow this practice.

Comment: `Some objects were not cleaned up when closing the scene` - this is exactly what can happen when C# code creates .NET objects when Unity isn't expecting it.  `static`s are the culprit.

Comment: BTW, when a Unity project gets to a reasonable size, devs tend to disable **Assembly Reload** so that entering **Play Mode** is significantly faster.   Unity does this by keeping the AppDomain from the prior run.  However any code that uses `static`s and isn't using `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`, fields rather than being initialised to `default` now start with the last run's value.  Whilst this may be fine for singleton `_instance` fields, it may lead to unexpected behaviour for say `int _playerScore` which won't start at zero.  It's much easier just to make the GameObject be the singleton