# How to remove the previous button listener before adding a new listener in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a **QuestionGenerator.cs** script which at the start, creates a question that is a comparison between two randomly generated numbers that can be up to 3 digits. When the user clicks on the correct option button, another random question is generated.

Let's say the numbers are `a` and `b`. I pass `a - b` and the array `{ "<", "=", ">" }` as the arguments to the method `SetButtonListeners()`. The logic goes like this:

- When `a - b` is less than `0`, the sign should be `<`
- When `a - b` is equal to `0`, the sign should be `=`
- When `a - b` is greater than `0`, the sign should be `>`

#### Actual question:

Every time `SetButtonListeners()` is called, listeners are *added* to the button, hence when it's called the second time, a listener already exists to that button. I want to remove the previously added listener if there's any and then add the new listener. As a hack, I am currently removing all the listeners the button has

```cs
buttons[i].onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
```

How do I go with only removing the previously set button listener and not all the listeners the button has?

---

A minimal reproducible code to depict my problem:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuestionsGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    static public QuestionsGenerator instance { get => return s_Instance; }
    static private QuestionsGenerator s_Instance;

    public Text questionText;
    public Button[] buttons; // length is 3

    private void Awake() {
        if (s_Instance == null) {
            s_Instance = this;
        } else {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Start() {
        GenerateQuestion();
    }

    private void GenerateQuestion() {
        ComparisionUpto3Digits();
    }

    private void ComparisionUpto3Digits() {
        int a = Random.Range(1, 1000);
        int b = Random.Range(1, 1000);

        questionText.text = a + " ___ " + b;

        int ans = a - b;
        string[] options = { "<", "=", ">" };
        SetButtonListeners(ans, options);
    }

    private void SetButtonListeners(int answer, string[] options) {
        // length of both buttons[] and options[] is the same
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++) {
            buttons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = options[i];

            // removing all listeners here
            buttons[i].onClick.RemoveAllListeners();

            if ((answer < 0 && i == 0) || (answer == 0 && i == 1) || (answer > 0 && i == 2)) {
                buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => {
                    HandleCorrectAnswer();
                });
            } else {
                buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => {
                    HandleWrongAnswer();
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleCorrectAnswer() {
        GenerateQuestion();
    }

    private void HandleWrongAnswer() {
        Debug.Log("Game Over");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `static`s in a Unity `MonoBehaviour`.  Remember Unity is a CLR Host much like SQL Server and IIS and can and will destroy all AppDomains including the primary AppDomain taking your `static`s along with it.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72592063/585968) how I like to implement singletons in Unity.

Comment: @MickyD, let's say I want to call singleton scripts from a bunch of other scripts, even in that case, do you want all of them to have a reference as `FindWithTag()` instead of just calling it using `GameManager.instance.SomeMethod()`? I can't digest the fact that using `static` instance in a singleton isn't recommended. Then why is it used so widely? I am not saying it's good because it's used widely, I am not convinced that using `static` can cause problems

Comment: Here’s an experiment you can do yourself.   On your script add a private static int _counter field.  As with other Int’s, don’t explicitly initialise it to 0.   Increment it in your Update().  Run the game.   It should increase with time.  Great.  Run it again. The values repeat starting at zero.  Great.  Now stop the game. Now disable Unity Domain Reload.  Run the game.  OH NO!!!! The game didn’t start with the counter at zero.   Now imagine someone bought something on the Asset Store with such code.  All because it used statics and it didn’t follow Unitys guidelines on statics.

Comment: Check out my implementation here. https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2021/10/17/flight-sim-project-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constantly adding new listeners does not seem like a good solution. Handle correct/wrong answer in the same listener instead by passing a different argument to the listening function. You can pass parameters like this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1288510/buttononclickaddlistener-how-to-pass-parameter-or.html

**EDIT**:
To be more precise, you can simply do something like this:

```
private int a,b;

private void Awake(){
    for(int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < buttons.Length; buttonIndex++){
        int closureIndex = buttonIndex;          
        buttons[closureIndex].onClick.AddListener(delegate{HandleAnswer(closureIndex);});
    }
}

private void HandleAnswer(int buttonIndex){
    int answer = a-b;
    if ((answer < 0 && buttonIndex == 0) || (answer == 0 && buttonIndex == 1) || (answer > 0 && buttonIndex == 2)) {
        [good answer]
    }else{
        [wrong answer]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Added closure index according to comment (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1376530/add-listeners-to-array-of-buttons.html?childToView=1376656#answer-1376656)

Comment: This indeed worked for me, but this code alone has an issue. There's a closure problem while adding listeners to an array of buttons, [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1376656/view.html) got it covered, take a look at it. Hence before adding a listener, initialise a variable `int closureIndex = buttonIndex;` and  use it as button index (`buttons[closureIndex]`) and pass it to the `HandleAnswer(closureIndex)` delegate. Accepted for this being helpful for finding a solution, edit your answer accordingly and earn an upvote :)

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that as I didn't run the code. Edited the answer, glad you found the solution.